# Запятая перед КАК в обороте

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужно ли обособлять оборот:

Вы(,) как человек старой закалки(,) понимаете, что...

Если обратиться к [грамоте](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183), то запятые, кажется, не нужны, потому что случай не подходит ни под один из трех описанных. Но интуиция подсказывает, что стоит поставить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые нужны, подробности - по тексту.

> Если обратиться к грамоте, то запятые, кажется, не нужны,

Не надо обращаться к "Грамоте". А если обратились, то имейте в виду, что её формулировки часто лукавы. В данном случае, указаны три случая, но нигде не упомянуто, что это отнюдь **не исчерпывающий список**.   Вас должно было насторожить наличие альтернативного списка, "где не ставится", из пяти пунктов. Понятно что случаев, где может использоваться оборот с "как", много больше, чем приведенных там "три плюс пять". И что делать в оставшихся, "Грамота" не раскрывает. Отсюда ваше непонимание.

К сожалению, эту фигню размножили и разнесли по многим и многим ресурсам не очень критичные копипастеры.

На самом деле правило надо формулировать так, что **обороты с "как" надо обособлять всегда, за исключением нескольких случаев** (их, правда, обычно выделяют больше пяти).

Вот как у Лопатина.

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=169
(§§ 64, 90)

> § 64. Обособляются запятыми приложения, имеющие при себе
>   присоединяющие их слова (по имени, по фамилии, по прозвищу, по
>   происхождению, родом и др.), а также союзы как (при осложненности
>   причинным значением) и или (при пояснительном значении):
>   ....
>   Ему, как человеку робкому и необщительному, прежде всего бросалось в
>   глаза то, чего у него никогда не было, а именно — необыкновенная
>   храбрость новых знакомых (Ч.); Как лицо служебное, милицейское, Сошнин
>   привык знакомиться с разным народом (Аст.); Лидия, или, как ее звали
>   дома, Лида, говорила больше с Белокуровым, чем со мной (Ч.).

Здесь все примеры - на один и тот же случай, тот же, что и у нас, первый просто тождественный даже по построению фразы.

> § 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно,
>   будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих
>   случаях: ...
>   (Здесь шесть пунктов, примерно совпадающие с "грамотными".  Нашего среди них нет.

Аналогично изложение идет у Розенталя.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=152#pp152

Таким образом, запятые необходимы: ***Вы, как человек старой закалки, понимаете, что...***

*Примечание*. Я не против использования проверочных "правил" типа "*как* в значении в *качестве*" против "*как* в значении *будучи*", но это все запоминалки, орфограммы, ни полноты, ни понимания сути они не обеспечивают. Что действительно надо усвоить, так это то, что обороты, подобные рассматриваемому, никак не являются оборотами типа "*как* в значении *в качестве*". Это сложный момент, в чем и можно убедиться на нашем примере ("вы в качестве человека старой закалки" - пусть и сомнительно, но не выглядит тут противоестественно). Проще удостовериться, что толкование "*как* в значении *будучи*" не проходит - и рассуждать от противного.

Answer (score 1):

*Вы, как человек старой закалки, понимаете... ~ Вы, будучи человеком старой закалки, понимаете...*

Запятые нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Вы, как человек старой закалки, понимаете..

Это оборот со значением **тождества** (не сравнения), а такие обороты не обособляются со значением "в качестве", но обособляются со значением причины.

В данном случае оборот имеет значение причины (так как вы являетесь человеком старой закалки).

Comment: Интересно, как значение *тождества* можно понять *"в качестве"*? Кто так излагает?